# C++ default Constructor not being called

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am very new to c++ so forgive me if I have overlooked something simple. I have a class Circle:

```
class Circle: public Shape{
protected:
     //string name;
     Point focus;
     float radius;
private:

public:
    virtual void calculateArea();
    virtual void calculatePerimeter();
    Circle();
    Circle(Point p, float r);
```

};

I have two constructors, one of which is the default which I have overloaded:

```
Circle::Circle()
{
    Point p(1,1);
    focus = p;
    radius = 10;
    name = "Circle";
    calculatePerimeter();
    calculateArea();
    cout<<"default circle"<<endl;
}
Circle::Circle(Point p, float r)
{
    focus = p;
    radius = r;
    name = "Circle";
    calculatePerimeter();
    calculateArea();
}
```

In my main I try to create two circles one using the each constructor, however the Circle being created with Circle() never gets created. I cannot for the life of me figure out why? There are no error messages or anything.

```
int main{
    Circle circle(a, 3.3);
    Circle c2();
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
 Circle c2();
```

Does not create an object, it declares a function by name `c2` which takes no argument and returns a `Circle` object. If you want to create a object just use:

```
Circle c2;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. I may have eventually noticed that if it wasn't 3am. I think its quitting time now.

Comment: Or better yet: `Circle c2{}` which is value-initialization and `Circle c2;` is default-initialization.

Comment: Oh BTW, that is not *most* vexing parse. It is just *vexing* parse. `Type1 a(Type2());` is *most* vexing parse.

Comment: @Nawaz, can you elaborate on the difference of Circle c2{ }; and Circle c2; ? that'll help others.

Comment: @ChanKim: Search *value-initialization* and *default-initialization* on this site.

Answer (score 8):

This here is not an instantiation, but a function declaration:

```
// parameter-less function c2, returns a Circle.
Circle c2();
```

You need

```
Circle c2;
```

or

```
Circle c2{};  // requires c++11
```