# Why does calling with empty parenthesis not call the default constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, default-constructor

**Context**

According to the [tutorial](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/), if a class defines a default constructor `Rectangle();`, it'sinvoked via:

```
int main () {
    Rectangle recta; // valid - default constructor
    Rectangle rectb(); // valid - but not a default constructor
    Rectangle rectc{}; // valid - default constructor
}
```

It is said that the second call is a "function declaration", so its interpreted by the compiler as some function that returns an object of type `Rectangle`. Yet in the [subsequent](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/) sections of that same tutorial, it refers to `Rectangle();` as a default constructor.

**Question(s)**

So this is a two part question:

1. Why are default constructors defined with `()` if calling with `()` does not even invoke them?
2. Why does the use of `{}` invoke the default constructor if defined with `()`?

**Thoughts/Examples**

*W.R.T the first item*, it seems contradictory that the default constructor definition must be either:

- Completely omitted, or
- Defined with empty parenthesis

Yet calling with empty parenthesis does not invoke the default constructor. The best that I can reason is that the compiler interprets the call to `rectb()` as some kind of "inline" function definition that returns an object of type `Rectangle`; because of this, if the default constructor had member assignment in it, this newly returned object would not have any members assigned and would all be `NULL` (or so I believe).

Now to expand the confusion with a detailed example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Circle
{
public:
    Circle(); // M1
    Circle(float r); // M2
};

Circle::Circle()
{
    cout << "default constructor" << endl;
}

Circle::Circle(float r)
{
    cout << "custom constructor" << endl;
}

int main() {
    Circle c1(1.0); // calls M2
    Circle c2(); // does not call M1
    return 0;
}

// Outputs
"custom constructor"
0
```

So if the compiler interprets a line such as `Circle c2();` as a newly declared function returning type `Circle`, why does it not do that for `Circle c1(1.0);` and is instead able to find a matching constructor?

*W.R.T. the second item*, I believe this is the result of a C++11 design implementation that enables to compiler to handle value-initialization from what I've read. Since it uses `{}` and not `()` the compiler does not parse this as a function declaration.

**References**

Now while I am researching this, the other questions I have found include:

1. [Default constructor with empty brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets)

Expands on something called the "most vexing parse" in C++, surrounding how `Circle c2();` is treated as a function declaration as noted. However, the question (#1) I am asking expands on this, namely why are what appear to be two function declarations treated differently despite having definitions within the class?

2. [C++ default Constructor not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615659/c-default-constructor-not-being-called)

Marked as a duplicate of the previous question, but with examples aligned to this post.

Comment: "Most vexing parse" is the keyword you're looking for.

Comment: Look up "most vexing parse" - put simply if a statement could be parsed as a function definition then it is a function definition. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: @RichardCritten I keep stumbling upon this, and have come to that conclusion. My confusion remains in why the "most vexing parse" applies to `Circle c2();` and not `Circle c1(1.0);` in my example. One is interpreted as a function declaration, the other calls a constructor, but why the difference?

Comment: `Circle c1(1.0);` can't be a function declaration, so it's not treated as one.

Comment: @madeslurpy the 2nd one cannot be (is not) a valid function declaration. A function declaration would look like `Circe c1(double)` Please note the type in the parenthesis as oposed to a value.

Comment: @bolov Thank you, I come from a Python background and haven't used C++ for much of anything in years. This implementation detail was confusing me greatly, and to know its as simple as that is frustrating yet relieving!

Comment: @RichardCritten -- if you look carefully at the page you linked to, you'll see that `Rectangle rectb();` is **not** an example of the most vexing parse. That refers to a more complex and more obscure issue. `Rectangle rectb();` is simply a function declaration. Yes, both come from the same rule, but that's not what makes it "vexing".

Comment: @PeteBecker Not sure I follow, admittedly in the tutorial its actually `Rectangle rectc();` but what's the different between just a function declaration and the most vexing parse?

Comment: @madeslurpy, Syntactically there _is no difference._ That's what makes it "vexing:" You have to know the special rule that applies in this special case. Modern C++ is the result of almost fifty years of gradual evolution. Not everything about it makes sense if you don't take that whole long history into account.

Comment: @madeslurpy -- if you tell a beginner that `int f();` is a function declaration,  they'll understand it. If you tell a beginner that `TimeKeeper time_keeper(Timer());` is a function declaration they'll be vexed. (that's the canonical example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse_)). It's partly a matter of degree, and partly about familiarity.

Comment: *"Why are default constructors defined with () if calling with () does not even invoke them?"* -- ah, but calling with () does invoke them --- but pay attention to the details! You are wondering why `rectb()` does not invoke `Rectangle()`. Notice the difference? The constructor `Rectangle()` can be invoked via `Rectangle()`, as in `Rectangle rectb = Rectangle();`. The problem comes when you try to invoke `Rectangle()` using *only* the parentheses. The syntax `Rectangle rectb();` requires interpretation -- to what do the parentheses belong? To the distant `Rectangle` or the closer `rectb`?